# GitLab: move repository from personal repository to team repository

Tags: gitlab, cicd

What I am trying to achieve:

I have a dozen of repositories under my personal repositories in GitLab, something like

```
https://gitlab-mycompany.com/me/projectone
https://gitlab-mycompany.com/me/projecttwo
...
https://gitlab-mycompany.com/me/projecteleven
```

Note, they are under my personal repositories, in this example referred as "me".
Some of them are public, some of them private, etc...

Now, my development is complete, I would like to hand over the repositories to my team.

Basically, I would like the result to be:

```
https://gitlab-mycompany.com/myteam/projectone
https://gitlab-mycompany.com/myteam/projecttwo
...
https://gitlab-mycompany.com/myteam/projecteleven
```

What I tried:

attempt 1: I create an **empty** repository at `https://gitlab-mycompany.com/myteam/projectone` From there, I make a PR with the content of `https://gitlab-mycompany.com/me/projectone`

While this is working, my sanity is going away, I have dozens of repo to repeat, and maybe more to come.

attempt 2: I searched on Google, and it seems there is a setting to "change path", please see the screenshot. However, the base part of the URL cannot be changed.

[image]

For example, in this randomly taken from the internet screenshot, I would like to change "PrivateCloud" to "myteam", but it is grayed out, not possible.

Question:

How can I easily move the repository from local repository to my team?